# Alternate output format for psql showing one column per line with column name

Tags: postgresql, output-formatting, psql

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 on Ubuntu. I have a table with columns `c1` through `cN`. The columns are wide enough that selecting all columns causes a row of query results to wrap multiple times. Consequently, the output is hard to read.

When the query results constitute just a few rows, it would be convenient if I could view the query results such that each column of each row is on a separate line, e.g.

```
 c1: <value of row 1's c1>
 c2: <value of row 1's c1>
 ...
 cN: <value of row 1's cN>
 ---- some kind of delimiter ----
 c1: <value of row 2's c1>
 etc.
```

I am running these queries on a server where I would prefer not to install any additional software. Is there a psql setting that will let me do something like that?

Answer (score 786, accepted):

I just needed to spend more time staring at the documentation.  This command:

```
\x on
```

will do exactly what I wanted.  Here is some sample output:

```
select * from dda where u_id=24 and dda_is_deleted='f';
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dda_id             | 1121
u_id               | 24
ab_id              | 10304
dda_type           | CHECKING
dda_status         | PENDING_VERIFICATION
dda_is_deleted     | f
dda_verify_op_id   | 44938
version            | 2
created            | 2012-03-06 21:37:50.585845
modified           | 2012-03-06 21:37:50.593425
c_id               | 
dda_nickname       | 
dda_account_name   | 
cu_id              | 1
abd_id             |
```

#### See also:

- [`man psql` => \x](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/postgresql-client-13/psql.1.en.html#:%7E:text=re%2Dexecuted%20instead.-,%5Cx,-%5B%20on%20%7C)
- [`man psql` => --expanded](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/postgresql-client-13/psql.1.en.html#:%7E:text=initial%20connection%20attempt.-,%2Dx,-%2D%2Dexpanded)
- [`man psql` => \pset => expanded](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/postgresql-client-13/psql.1.en.html#:%7E:text=is%20a%20comma.-,expanded,-(or%20x))

Comment: You can also try \pset format wrapped (allowed formats are unaligned, aligned, wrapped, html, latex, troff-ms).  If the display is narrow enough it will word wrap each column.

Comment: `\x` alone will toggle the value, saving you three keystrokes! (Useful when you rapidly switch between wide and narrow outputs).

Comment: If you looking for equivalent to `\G` from Mysql, try append `\x\g\x` to the end of query or define shortcut in `~/.psqlrc` adding `\set G '\\set QUIET 1\\x\\g\\x\\set QUIET 0'`, then use on the end `:G`. (note lack of semicolons)

Comment: Is it possible to somehow pass "`\x on`" or the equivalent at the command line?  It'd be nice if I could just save  (for instance, by using a bash shell alias) `psql --something` so that I always have the option turned on by default.

Comment: @machineghost Use `-P expanded=auto` or `--pset expanded=auto`

Comment: @alecdwm I am using pgcli 2.0.0 and this flag does not exists. I managed to solve this issue by going to https://www.pgcli.com/config and modifying my config file

Comment: @Simon - `pgcli` is not the same program as `psql` ;)

Comment: How do you get it to display like that and not with html table element (`<td>`, `<tr>` etc.)?

Comment: @machineghost, yes, you can use this to have it run the current query with expansion turned on: `\gx`

Answer (score 363):

### (New) Expanded Auto Mode: \x auto

[New for Postgresql 9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.2.0/#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20display%20mode%20to%20auto%2Dexpand); PSQL automatically fits records to the width of the screen. previously you only had expanded mode on or off and had to switch between the modes as necessary.

- If the record can fit into the width of the screen; psql uses normal formatting.
- If the record can **not** fit into the width of the screen; psql uses expanded mode.

To get this use: **\x auto**

[Postgresql 9.5 Documentation on PSQL command.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html)

---

Wide screen, normal formatting:

```
 id | time  |       humanize_time             | value 
----+-------+---------------------------------+-------
  1 | 09:30 |  Early Morning - (9.30 am)      |   570
  2 | 11:30 |  Late Morning - (11.30 am)      |   690
  3 | 13:30 |  Early Afternoon - (1.30pm)     |   810
  4 | 15:30 |  Late Afternoon - (3.30 pm)     |   930
(4 rows)
```

---

Narrow screen, expanded formatting:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 1
time          | 09:30
humanize_time | Early Morning - (9.30 am)
value         | 570
-[ RECORD 2 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 2
time          | 11:30
humanize_time | Late Morning - (11.30 am)
value         | 690
-[ RECORD 3 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 3
time          | 13:30
humanize_time | Early Afternoon - (1.30pm)
value         | 810
-[ RECORD 4 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 4
time          | 15:30
humanize_time | Late Afternoon - (3.30 pm)
value         | 930
```

---

#### How to start psql with \x auto?

Configure `\x auto` command on startup by adding it to `.psqlrc` in your home folder and restarting psql. [Look under 'Files' section in the psql doc for more info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html).

**~/.psqlrc**

```
\x auto
```

Comment: What option is available to fully enclose `normal formatted` tables with `dashes`? I like an outer enclosing box too, the way `MySQL` does it.

Answer (score 94):

You have so many choices, how could you be confused :-)?  The main controls are:

```
# \pset format
# \H
# \x
# \pset pager off
```

Each has options and interactions with the others.  The most automatic options are:

```
# \x off;\pset format wrapped
# \x auto
```

The newer "\x auto" option switches to line-by-line display only "if needed".

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------
id          | 6
description | This is a gallery of oilve oil brands.
authority   | I love olive oil, and wanted to create a place for
reviews and comments on various types.
-[ RECORD 2 ]---------------
id          | 19
description | XXX Test A 
authority   | Testing
```

The older "\pset format wrapped" is similar in that it tries to fit the data neatly on screen, but falls back to unaligned if the headers won't fit.  Here's an example of wrapped:

```
 id |          description           |            authority            
----+--------------------------------+---------------------------------
  6 | This is a gallery of oilve     | I love olive oil, and wanted to
    ; oil brands.                    ;  create a place for reviews and
    ;                                ;  comments on various types.
 19 | Test Test A                    | Testing
```

Comment: `\x auto` with `\pset pager off` is a nice one.

Comment: Are `\x off; \pset format wrapped` and `\x auto` intended to be used together or are they mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 34):

One interesting thing is we can view the tables horizontally, without folding. we can use `PAGER` environment variable. psql makes use of it. you can set

```
export PAGER='/usr/bin/less -S'
```

or just `less -S` if its already availble in command line, if not with the proper location. -S to view unfolded lines. you can pass in any custom viewer or other options with it.

I've written more in [Psql Horizontal Display](https://learnersguide.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/psql-horizontal-table-display/)

Comment: Answer is really good. I am surprised it's not marked higher.  Perfect for anyone working in a terminal.

Comment: This was extremely helpful

Comment: This is useful, but how do you scroll to the right?

Comment: @NieldeWet for me using the right and left arrows to scroll horizontally works. But I expected to be able to do this using VIM bindings, but it works.

Answer (score 28):

[`pspg`](https://github.com/okbob/pspg) is a simple tool that offers advanced table formatting, horizontal scrolling, search and many more features.

```
git clone https://github.com/okbob/pspg.git
cd pspg
./configure
make
make install
```

then make sure to update `PAGER` variable e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`

```
export PAGER="pspg -s 6"
```

where `-s` stands for color scheme (`1-14`). If you're using [pgdg repositories](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) simply install a package (on Debian-like distribution):

```
sudo apt install pspg
```

[image: pspg example]

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking for psql `command-line mode` like me,

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323549/248616) is the syntax `--pset expanded=auto`

> psql command-line options: 
> -P expanded=auto 
> --pset expanded=auto 
> -x 
> --expanded 
> ...

Another way is `-q` option [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723629/248616)

Comment: If you have multiple `-P` or `--pset` commands you can combine them like this. Here is a command I use to send to docker container `docker exec -it pgsql-container psql -P pager=off -P expanded=auto -U me -c "select * from main;"`

Answer (score 7):

Also be sure to check out \H, which toggles HTML output on/off.  Not necessarily easy to read at the console, but interesting for dumping into a file (see \o) or pasting into an editor/browser window for viewing, especially with multiple rows of relatively complex data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **zenity** utility to display the query's output as html table.

- First implement a bash script with the following codes:

  ```
  cat > '/tmp/sql.op';
  zenity --text-info  --html --filename='/tmp/sql.op';
  ```

- Then, save it like **mypager.sh**
- Then, set and export the environment variable PAGER with the absolute path of the script.

  ```
  i.e.,  export PAGER='/path/mypager.sh'
  ```

- Then login to the psql cli and execute the below command

  ```
  \H
  ```
- Finally execute any query, a tabled output will be displayed with the zenity utility as an html tabled format.

Comment: very useful output, works like a charm!