# How to set default display mode in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

Almost every psql query comes out an illegible mess if not preceded by [display configuration commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604723/alternate-output-format-for-psql) such as `\x auto`. Typing this manually for each psql instance is annoying.

> Expanded display is used automatically.

Is there any way to configure a better default display? Or perhaps the answer is to use a more advanced interactive terminal?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88543

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I'd been searching for 'psql config file' but somehow wasn't able to find that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Use `.psqlrc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) to set defaults.

For the specific case of `\x`, newer `psql` versions (9.3, I think, but it might just be the 9.4 pre-release) can automatically switch to expanded output mode when the rows are too wide to fit on a line. From `\?`:

> \x [on|off|auto]       toggle expanded output (currently off)

So I suggest putting `\x auto` in your `.psqlrc`, rather than forcing it to `on`.

Comment: on psql 9.3.7 ubuntu 14, the file is located at /var/lib/postgresql/.psqlrc if you use psql as postgres user (sudo -u postgres psql)

Answer (score 20):

It should also be noted that the `psql` command line option `-x` or `--expanded` is the same as using `\x` from within.

---

### `psql` command-line options:

```
-P expanded=auto
--pset expanded=auto
-x
--expanded
```

### within the `psql` shell:

```
\x
```

Comment: Also to note: the `psql` command line option `-P expanded=auto` or `--pset expanded=auto` is the same as using `\x auto` from within.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option of -x but it does not do the job for me as I am using COPY to send output to a file. Without copy "-x" works well!

So here is what I have done to read:

```
# psql -U postgres -o /tmp/output_file_name.txt <<EOF
\x
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
EOF

Expanded display is on.
```

One can morph the above to whatever he/she needs to do. 
One can also do the same with an input file.

Answer (score 0):

For me I add -q to turn that off for my psql command
e.g.

```
psql postgresql://u:p@h:5432/db  -q            -c 'select 1'
#    connection string           turn it off   query
```