# Use jsonb_pretty for all printed JSONB in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, psql, jsonb

Can `.psqlrc` be configured so that `jsonb_pretty` is applied to every JSONB column printed to console?

Expanded display automatic mode is very useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108898/1007926

I want to use both `jsonb_pretty` and expanded display.  Does `jsonb_pretty` work by inserting newlines into the string?  I suppose this would this cause problems if applied to every JSONB `select`.

`jsonb_pretty`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. `psql` has not any support for pretty print of JSON types.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this is no longer correct; psql versions greater than 9.5 support `jsonb_pretty(field_name)`, as the OP seems to be aware. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230928/9154668).

Answer (score 0):

With just psql I guess @Pavel_Stehule is right (so Not).

With [SQLTT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqltt) you can hack it with the use of [hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqltt#hooks).

**Example:**

```
// users.sql.js

const sqltt = require("sqltt");
const getUserData = new sqltt({                                               
    hooks: {                                                                
        // Prettier formatting on CLI output:                               
        user_profile: (arg, eng) => eng.match(/(^|_)cli$/) && "jsonb_pretty("+arg+") as "+arg,              
    },                                                                      
    sql: $=>$`                                                              
        select id, name, ${$.literal("user_profile")}                       
        from users                                                          
        where id = ${"userId"} 
    `,                                                                      
});
sqltt.publish(module, {getUserData});
```

Then you can...

**Install sqltt:**

```
user@host:~/sqltttest$ npm install sqltt                                    
(...)
```

**List available queries in file:**

```
user@host:~/sqltttest$ node user.sql.js                                     
Available queries:                                                          
✓ getUserData:  (Undocumented)
```

**Get psql suitable query (with arguments already interpolated):**

```
user@host:~/sqltttest$ node user.sql.js getUserData 'John Smith'            
\set userId '''John Smith'''                                                
        select id, name, jsonb_pretty(user_profile) as user_profile         
        from users                                                          
        where id = :userId
```

**...pipe it directly to psql:**

```
user@host:~/sqltttest$ node user.sql.js getUserData 'John Smith' | psql myDatabase
\set userId '''John Smith'''                                                
        select id, name, jsonb_pretty(user_profile) as user_profile         
        from users                                                          
        where id = :userId
```

**Use it from Node.js project:**

```
const {getUserData, ...otherSQL} = require("./user.sql.js");                
const sql = getUserData.sql();                                              
// select id, name, user_profile                                            
// from users                                                               
// where id = $1
```

**Obtain non-cli sql to use with other languages:**

```
user@host:~/sqltttest$ node user.sql.js --engine=_nocli getUserData         
                                                                            
        select id, name, user_profile                                       
        from users                                                          
        where id = $1
```

**...and, of course, store it in plain sql file:**

```
user@host:~/sqltttest$ node user.sql.js --engine=_nocli getUserData > getUserData.sql
```