# SQL: What is the equivalent of json_pretty() in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, dataformat

What is the equivalent of this MySQL function

```
SELECT JSON_PRETTY('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}') AS Result
  FROM table;
```

Formatted JSON:

```
+------------------------------+
| Result                       |
+------------------------------+
| {                            |
|   "a": 1,                    |
|   "b": 2,                    |
|   "c": 3                     |
| }                            |
+------------------------------+
```

I've tried **`jsonb_pretty()`** as mentioned in the document but nothing is available

Comment: jsonb_pretty  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7132d613c7fe4adbed9971e2c3266153

Answer (score 21):

You want **`jsonb_pretty()`**, that is available in Postgres [since *version 9.5*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.5.0/#AEN132010):

```sql
SELECT jsonb_pretty('{"a":1, "aa":2, "c":3, "b":4, "b":5}') AS result
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZJ7SZeNA)**:

```json
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": 3,
    "aa": 2
}
```

The [`jsonb` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) forces internal key order, so casting to it might reorder your `json`. It also discards whitespace between tokens and keeps only the last value for duplicate keys. Casting from `json` to `jsonb` and back will not restore the original order, whitespace or the duplicate keys.

**`jsonb_pretty()`** works on `jsonb` datatype only. If your input is `json`, you need to [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) it first. As a formatting function, it returns type `text`, similar to how [MySQL's `json_pretty()` returns `longtext`](https://dbfiddle.uk/7dUbNkCJ). Cast it back to `json`/`jsonb` or revert to the unprocessed value to continue using json [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Comment: One method of casting is `::<type>`   That is, eg here, `'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'` **`::jsonb`**

Comment: Should be marked as answer