# How can I get pretty printed JSON from a Postgres SQL query in psql?

Tags: json, postgresql, psql, pretty-print

I have JSON data stored as regular strings in my Postgres tables.  When I select them in the `psql` client, I want these strings to be pretty-printed so that I can see the data more easily.

Can I do this without running the output through an external program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: What is the equivalent of json\_pretty() in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230223/sql-what-is-the-equivalent-of-json-pretty-in-postgresql)

Comment: That answers a question that a MySQL user, familiar with the json_pretty() function in MySQL, might have.  My question is meant to be what I came looking for--how do I pretty-print json in Postgres.  I don't think the question you linked should be altered, because "how do I do X from mysql in postgres" is an exceedingly common thing for people to ask.  Also, search results for this were all over the place.  I put in a question and answer that matched what I was looking for and will hopefully match the *search* of future seekers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `jsonb_pretty`--just cast the data to type `jsonb` first:

```
with data (text_json_blob) as (
  values
    ('{"something":"simple"}'),
    ('{"foo":"bar", "qux":["toto","tata","titi","tutu"]}')
)
select
  jsonb_pretty(text_json_blob :: jsonb) as nice_json
from
  data;
```

Output (I started the client with `psql -A` to strip some extraneous output):

```
nice_json
{
    "something": "simple"
}
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "qux": [
        "toto",
        "tata",
        "titi",
        "tutu"
    ]
}
(2 rows)
```

`jsonb_pretty` was [added in Postgres 9.5](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/JSON_pretty)