# formatting the data while exporting to a file?

Tags: postgresql

I want the output as below format in the output file.

```
Expected OUTPUT:

Table CUSTOMERMSTR
---------------------------

custno         cjd          custtype
-------------- ----------- ------------
cust123      01-OCT-1900           1 
cust123      08-SEP-1997           1 
cust123      01-JAN-1996           1 

3 rows
```

AS of NOW:

```
Table CUSTOMERMSTR
----------------------------

custno|to_char|custtype
cust123|01-OCT-1900|1
cust123|08-SEP-1997|1
cust123|01-JAN-1996|1
```

This is my expdata.psql file in the UNIX server.
This is not giving the expecting format.

Please help me with what I have to add to get the desired output in my .psql script.

```
--col custno  format 9999999  heading "custno"              
--col cjd   format A25 heading "cjd"    
--col custtype  format 999999999    heading "custtype"       

\t off
\a
\echo 

\echo Table CUSTOMERMSTR
\echo ----------------------------

\echo
select custno,TO_CHAR(cjd,'DD-MON-YYYY'),custtype   from CUSTOMERMSTR;
```

Comment: Please describe the difference between the output you show and the output you expect.

Comment: Expected OUTPUT:

Table CUSTOMERMSTR
---------------------------

custno         cjd          custtype
-------------- ----------- ------------
cust123      01-OCT-1900           1 
cust123      08-SEP-1997           1 
cust123      01-JAN-1996           1 

3 rows 


AS of NOW:

Table CUSTOMERMSTR
----------------------------

custno|to_char|custtype
cust123|01-OCT-1900|1
cust123|08-SEP-1997|1
cust123|01-JAN-1996|1

Comment: I have edited my original post with expected and current output.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604723/alternate-output-format-for-psql

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want exactly that many spaces in your output?

Comment: Not exactly same spaces.